# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de un tabla en Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Saludos comunidad. Necesito cambiar el nombre de una tabla en Rails, quisiera saber si hay una forma que Rails cambie de forma automatica el nombre de esa tabla en los controladores e vista donde se vea afectado. Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es que el modelo apunte a una tabla en específico

```
class Modelo < ApplicationRecord    
  self.table_name = 'Nombre_de_la_tabla'
end
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el nombre de tabla, debes crear una migración y agregar

```
def change
  rename_table :nombre_antiguo, :nombre_nuevo
end
```

El resto (cambio de controladores, vistas, modelos, etc) no hay una forma automatizada de hacerlo y lamentablemente tienes que realizarlo de forma manual.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias! Saludos.